# Hi can I please get my question off hold status now

Tags: support

I have a question about my Philosophy Stack Exchange post: [Is legislation that denies us the freedom to change our consciousness good or bad and WHY?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/50764/is-legislation-that-denies-us-the-freedom-to-change-our-consciousness-good-or-ba)

Yea Hi  I'm new they just asked me to rephrase the question and I did. Its very clear and blunt now, been two days. Please take it off hold I am eager to see what everyone thinks!  thank you    Great Site!

Comment: The question is still very broad/vague. What is the actual specific problem in your study of philosophy? What sort of philosophical research have you conducted so far; what hypotheses have you formed? *What exactly are you hoping for someone here to (briefly) explain to you?*

Comment: +1 I agree with you about entheogens, however, the question you ask is a political one: *How to get free of a legal cage?* That the question is on hold is not a bad thing. It forces you to think of a different question. Also, I doubt that anyone here can answer your question except in a general way.

Comment: Ok good points guys.. But its obvious to me it almost has to be political to get at what im driving at.. maybe this is best for a different forum but I really wanted a philosophical swing on it before I brought it into the realm of the law because in all actuality I may do just that..And lets face it the thought of a law precedes the writing of one...

Comment: Everything is governed by some kind of law these days.. My biggest problem really is that not only (and if this isn't big enough) we do not have legal control over our own mind,consciousness in general but if we have an ailment mental or physical we can not treat our own bodies from the physical resources this world avails to us.. I can think of a few examples, both specific and incredibly wide spread.  Because people cant afford to pay for a certain exspnsive "medication" that was synthesized from a plant which laws were created around to prevent its use,

Comment: Or molecules that are psychoactive and because it gives off a type of "high" it can't be considered medicine like KETAMINE- you guys will (hopefully) see this in the news this winter.. That the government would rather see  American professors and war veterans(just true stories I've read today on forums) depressed literally to the point of committing suicide than recover and lead joyous lives once again at the risk that they may feel too good  for some hours of the day?   Oh but really, god for bid they get addicted,  What about the opiate epidemic?

Comment: Can you guys help me formulate a question here you kinda know what Im getting at.. I want to approach this legally but from what basis other than intrinsic personal freedom being born, just so happens to be inside their political imaginary lines...Any ideas how to start this topic rolling?

Comment: You might ask a question like this: "To what extent can we trust the experiences we have when under the influence of a substance?" My questions are also closed so I don't know if I have a sense of what will pass.  All you need is five people voting to close a question without anyone wanting to leave it open for the question to be closed.

Comment: Thanks frank I was just doing that check it out now

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all, I did my best structuring the post for better readability.

The problems of the question remain:

- It is bloated. While giving context is generally a good thing, in this case, there is a whole lot of information that is not really necessary for understanding and answering the question (esp. the part about different locally used substances)
- It is not about philosophy in particular. While this is a site on philosophy, it is not a place to *discuss* related issues. The idea of StackExchange is to establish a database of questions on philosophical knowledge, not to produce original philosophy.
- It is not exactly clear what your question actually is. Mind, you should try to formulate one single concise question. This is actually very hard. Every student of philosophy can tell you this is the hardest part of academic work. If you have multiple questions, split them into multiple posts. This way they can later be found by people having the same question(s).

To offer help: I would suggest asking about philosophers (reference-request being the tag to go) who wrote about the ethics of entheogens. For most topics, you will find authors discussing pros and cons in applied ethics. A quick search on scholar.google.com for "ethics entheogens" had an output of 733 hits. Also, try to omit everything that is not necessary for understanding and answering the question. Omitting unnecessary noise makes it easier to read and more likely to be answered.

By editing it to be a reference-request rather than asking for opinions you can get answers and further reading and make it a good fit for SE (look [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) for what to avoid).

Comment: Hmmm yea a lot of good points i need to brush up on my search skills to start thanks..  how bout any opinion on this new philosophy? I'm getting tired of the protocol and just wanna get down to what I'm driving at ya know...

Comment: Oh i just saw the re-structuring or the question Nice work! thanks man! I'm new here first question actually.